# spring download excel file

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, swagger-2.0

I have following controller to download excel file. The file is downloaded but when I open it I get "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.". What I'm doing wrong in my controller?

```
@ApiOperation(value = "export ontology")
@RequestMapping(value = "/export/{ontologyId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> exportExcel(@PathVariable Long ontologyId) throws FileNotFoundException {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=pfizer_polish_ontology.xlsx");
    headers.add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    headers.add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    headers.setContentType(
            MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));

    File file = new File("C:\\ttt\\pfizer_polish_ontology.xlsx");

    InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(file.length()).headers(headers).body(isr);
}
```

**I want to add maybe a important detail**
I'm using Swagger interface to REST APIs

Using POSTMAN (Save and Download) I was able to download the file and it's good. So seems the problem is only when using swagger interface

Comment: a simple and maybe stupid observation... is the file C:\\ttt\\pfizer_polish_ontology.xlsx ok? Is it possible that this file is corrupted and so the downloaded file is corrupted?

Comment: the file is good for 100%. I just opened it from main location without problem

Comment: Just tried your code and everything works as expected, both in Firefox (54.0.1) and Chrome (60.0.3112.113). Hope your problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, code work fine. That's swagger issue. Using postman the API works fine

Comment: Did you able solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is the one that I used for xlsx document:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Comment: I just updated the code in my initial post with your proposed contentType - and does not work

Comment: The way we did it was by getting the `OutputStream` from `HttpServletResponse` and writing it to this output stream. See the modified code.

Comment: where I can see the "modified code". do you published it ?

Answer (score 1):

I bet your content type is not matching the Excel format. The followin should be enough:

```
contentType("application/csv")
```

Anyway, I suggest you to take a look on the webpage describing shirtly the [MIME Types](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/). As far as I see the format xsl(x) would match the best all of these:

```
application/excel
application/vnd.ms-excel
application/x-excel
application/x-msexcel
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? You have to specify your problem and describe the error.

Comment: i get the same error when try to open downloaded file "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.". the file is downloaded but it's corrupt